# GTK3 Detect user resizing window

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk

This is some example code from the *Gnome* website:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void resizechange() {
    printf("User resized window!\n");
}

static void
activate (GApplication *app,
          gpointer      user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *widget;

  widget = gtk_application_window_new (GTK_APPLICATION (app));
  gtk_widget_show (widget);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gnome.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Is there a way that the `resizechange()` function could be run when the user resizes the program window, so I can act upon this?

Can this be done with events or callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by connecting to the [`configure-event`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-configure-event) signal of your widget.

However, your callback **must** respect the function signature stated in the documentation, so instead of:

```
static void resizechange()
```

you will have:

```
static gboolean resizechange (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
```

Comment: Ok I have updated my code and put this in the main function g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (resizechange), NULL);

But I still get runtime errors, Is this not just for GtkWidgets and not GtkApplication, how can I use this in my code, thanks @liberforce

Comment: Please read the documentation for g_signal_connect. The second argument is the name of the signal you connect to. Connecting your `resizechange` callback to the `activate` signal doesn't make sense. You need to connect it to the `configure-event` signal, as stated in my answer.